# Calculate who cross the finish line first (C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have already solved the timer and record the time of someone who crosses the finish line . But I don't have any idea on how to calculate who's the first one who crosses the finish line . Could someone give me some idea here's my code

```
public float timer = 0f;

float currentTimeBot1 = 0f;
float currentTimeBot2 = 0f;
float currentTimeBot3 = 0f;
float currentTimeBot4 = 0f;
float currentTimeBot5 = 0f;
float currentTimePlayer = 0f;

float bestTime = 0f;

bool first, second, third, startrace, finishrace;

public GameObject startCountDown;

private void Start()
{
    //startrace = true;
    StartCoroutine(waitForTheCountdown());
}

private void Update()
{
    if (startrace)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        timer = 0f;
    }

}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Bot1"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Bot1 Finished");
        currentTimeBot1 = timer;
        Debug.Log(currentTimeBot1.ToString());
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Bot2"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Bot2 Finished");
        currentTimeBot2 = timer;
        Debug.Log(currentTimeBot2.ToString());
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Bot3"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Bot3 Finished");
        currentTimeBot3 = timer;
        Debug.Log(currentTimeBot3.ToString());
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Bot4"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Bot4 Finished");
        currentTimeBot4 = timer;
        Debug.Log(currentTimeBot4.ToString());
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Bot5"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Bot5 Finished");
        currentTimeBot5 = timer;
        Debug.Log(currentTimeBot5.ToString());
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Player Finished");
        currentTimePlayer = timer;
        Debug.Log(currentTimePlayer.ToString());
    }


}

private IEnumerator waitForTheCountdown()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(6f);
    if (startCountDown.GetComponent<StartCountdown>().raceStarted == true)
    {
        startrace = true;
    }
    else
    {
        startrace = false;
    }
}
```

I tried this kind of formula but it's too long and only work for some cases

```
if(currentTimePlayer > currentTimeBot1 || currentTimePlayer > currentTimeBot2 || currentTimePlayer > currentTimeBot3 || currentTimePlayer > currentTimeBot4 || currentTimePlayer > currentTimeBot5){
       Debug.Log("1st!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply store them all in a List (and in general use `if-else` or maybe even `switch-case` for better performance)

```
public List<GameObject> winners = new List<GameObject>();

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    switch(other.gameObject.tag)
    {
        case "Bot1":
            Debug.Log("Bot1 Finished");
            currentTimeBot1 = timer;
            Debug.Log(currentTimeBot1.ToString());
            break;

        case "Bot2":
            Debug.Log("Bot2 Finished");
            currentTimeBot2 = timer;
            Debug.Log(currentTimeBot2.ToString());
            break;

        case "Bot3":
            Debug.Log("Bot3 Finished");
            currentTimeBot3 = timer;
            Debug.Log(currentTimeBot3.ToString());
            break;

        case "Bot4":
            Debug.Log("Bot4 Finished");
            currentTimeBot4 = timer;
            Debug.Log(currentTimeBot4.ToString());
            break;

        case "Bot5":
            Debug.Log("Bot5 Finished");
            currentTimeBot5 = timer;
            Debug.Log(currentTimeBot5.ToString());
            break;

        case "Player":
            Debug.Log("Player Finished");
            currentTimePlayer = timer;
            Debug.Log(currentTimePlayer.ToString());
            break;

        default:
            return;
    }

    // this is only matched if one of the before tags matched
    winners.Add(other.gameObject);
}
```

This way you don't only get the first winner (`winners[0]`) but actually you can get the whole order in which they finished e.g.

```
for(var i = 0; i< winners.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.LogFormat("{0}. {1}", i + 1, winners[i].name);
}
```

---

If you also need the finish times still than rather use a dictionary like

```
public Dictionary<GameObject, float> winners = new Dictionary<GameObject, float>();

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    switch(other.gameObject.tag)
    {
        case "Bot1":
            winners.Add(other.gameObject, timer);
            break;
    }

    // ...

    Debug.Log(other.gameObject.tag + " Finished");
    Debug.Log(winners[other.gameObject].ToString());
}
```

again access eihter the first one like

```
var winner = winners[0].key;
var bestTime = winners[0].value;
```

or iterate over all winners

```
foreach(var kvp in winners)
{
    var winner = kvp.key;
    var finishTime = kvp.value;
    //...
}
```

or access a specific GameObjects finish time

```
var finishTime = winners[aCertainGameObject];
```